# AWS S3 to BigQuery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

created a transfer to BigQuery and configured uploading data to a table, config settings:

```
 Data source details

Destination table
    conversion_paths 
Amazon S3 URI
    s3://af-ext-reports/2d8f-***/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt={run_time-24h|"%Y-%m-%d"}/*/part* 
Access key ID
    ****** 
Secret access key
    ******
File format
    CSV 
Number of errors allowed
    5 
Decimal target types
    None
Ignore unknown values
    None
Field delimiter
    , 
Header rows to skip
    0 
Allow quoted newlines
    None
Allow jagged rows
    None
```

I start the transfer, but the data is not uploaded to the table, the transfer log:

```
4:55:24 PM  Summary: succeeded 0 jobs, failed 0 jobs.   
4:55:03 PM  No files found matching: "s3://.../2d8f-***/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt=2021-03-24/*/part* "   
4:55:03 PM  Processing files from Amazon S3 matching: "s3://af-ext-reports/2d8f-***/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt=2021-03-24/*/part* "   
4:55:03 PM  Moving data from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud complete: Moved 101 object(s).   
4:52:59 PM  Starting transfer from Amazon S3 for files with prefix: "s3://af-ext-reports/2d8f-***/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt=2021-03-24/"     
4:52:59 PM  Starting transfer from Amazon S3 for files modified before 2021-03-25T07:42:59-07:00 (exclusive).   
4:52:57 PM  Transfer load date: 20210325    
4:52:56 PM  Dispatched run to data source with id 2215280434122918
```

although when I check the files through the console, the files are

```
aws s3 ls s3://af-ext-reports/2d8f-***/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt=2021-03-24/h=23/
2021-03-25 16:57:28     126474 part-00000.gz
2021-03-25 16:57:29     124885 part-00001.gz
...
```

Why are the files not uploaded to the table through the transfer?

Comment: it looks like the problem was in the last space in the line:
`s3://af-ext-reports/2d8f-acc-HpRzWu5G-2d8f/data-locker-hourly/t=conversion_paths/dt={run_time-24h|"%Y-%m-%d"}/*/part*`

I removed the space at the end of the line and the transfer worked

Comment: That's worthy of answering your own question and accepting it :)